# Android keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

My application starts with a bunch of text input fields, and I want that when starting up the the application. The virtual keyboard isn't open, but opens only when I click on one of the textinput fields.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

In your `onCreate` method you could get your first text view and call `requestFocus()` on it. This ought to focus this field when the activity starts and bring up a virtual keyboard if needed.

If you want the keyboard *not* to appear on startup, request focus for a non-text element like a button.

Comment: Sorry, your question was unclear. Do you have any other focusable elements in your application such as a button? Set one of those to focus instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should leave the input method to the user.  They might be using a physical keyboard or maybe even something like speech to text.

Comment: i dont want to get the keyboard to appear ... iwant the keyboard to NOT appear

Comment: In that case just don't present an editable field.  There's not much reason to have one if you want to block the input method.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this approach to hide the keyboard after the user searches. You could use this in our `onCreate` method:

[Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Quote from Reto Meier's accepted solution:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```